# gaussian sum filter for irregular spaced points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gaussian, smoothing

I have a set of points (x,y) as two vectors
x,y for example:

```
from pylab import *
x = sorted(random(30))
y = random(30)
plot(x,y, 'o-')
```

[image]

Now I would like to smooth this data with a Gaussian and evaluate it only at certain (regularly spaced) points on the x-axis. lets say for:

```
x_eval = linspace(0,1,11)
```

I got the tip that this method is called a "Gaussian sum filter", but so far I have not found any implementation in numpy/scipy for that, although it seems like a standard problem at first glance.
As the x values are not equally spaced I can't use the scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter1d.

Usually this kind of smoothing is done going through furrier space and multiplying with the kernel, but I don't really know if this will be possible with irregular spaced data.

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will blow up for very large datasets, but the proper calculaiton you are asking for would be done as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0) # for repeatability
x = np.random.rand(30)
x.sort()
y = np.random.rand(30)

x_eval = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
sigma = 0.1

delta_x = x_eval[:, None] - x
weights = np.exp(-delta_x*delta_x / (2*sigma*sigma)) / (np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * sigma)
weights /= np.sum(weights, axis=1, keepdims=True)
y_eval = np.dot(weights, y)

plt.plot(x, y, 'bo-')
plt.plot(x_eval, y_eval, 'ro-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How would this be implemente for a 2D data set?

Comment: One possible optimization would be to only evaluate points within a window. (The window size can be calculated heuristically on the first pass). A more advanced method might even construct a k-d tree...

Answer (score 4):

I'll preface this answer by saying that this is more of a DSP question than a programming question...

...that being said there, there is a simple two step solution to your problem.

**Step 1: Resample the data**

So to illustrate this we can create a random data set with unequal sampling:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(0,100,100))
y = np.random.normal(0,1,size=100)
```

This gives something like:

[image: Unevenly sampled data]

We can resample this data using simple linear interpolation:

```
nx = np.arange(x.max()) # choose new x axis sampling
ny = np.interp(nx,x,y) # generate y values for each x
```

This converts our data to:

[image: Same data resampled evenly]

**Step 2: Apply filter**

At this stage you can use some of the tools available through `scipy` to apply a Gaussian filter to the data with a given sigma value:

```
import scipy.ndimage.filters as filters
fx = filters.gaussian_filter1d(ny,sigma=100)
```

Plotting this up against the original data we get:

[image: Gaussian filter applied]

The choice of the `sigma` value determines the width of the filter.

Comment: This will give data points a weight proportional to the x-distance to their next neighbours. This is usually not what one would want: If one assumes equal measurement noise in each data-point, to maximise SNR, one should put equal weight to each data point. Jaime's answer is correct in that regard.

Comment: Superficially, this works. However, as @burnpanck said, this gives a larger bias to certain points over others.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Jaime's answer I wrote a function that implements this with some additional documentation and the ability to discard estimates far from the datapoints.

I think confidence intervals could be obtained on this estimate by bootstrapping, but I haven't done this yet.

```
def gaussian_sum_smooth(xdata, ydata, xeval, sigma, null_thresh=0.6):
    """Apply gaussian sum filter to data.
    
    xdata, ydata : array
        Arrays of x- and y-coordinates of data. 
        Must be 1d and have the same length.
    
    xeval : array
        Array of x-coordinates at which to evaluate the smoothed result
    
    sigma : float
        Standard deviation of the Gaussian to apply to each data point
        Larger values yield a smoother curve.
    
    null_thresh : float
        For evaluation points far from data points, the estimate will be
        based on very little data. If the total weight is below this threshold,
        return np.nan at this location. Zero means always return an estimate.
        The default of 0.6 corresponds to approximately one sigma away 
        from the nearest datapoint.
    """
    # Distance between every combination of xdata and xeval
    # each row corresponds to a value in xeval
    # each col corresponds to a value in xdata
    delta_x = xeval[:, None] - xdata

    # Calculate weight of every value in delta_x using Gaussian
    # Maximum weight is 1.0 where delta_x is 0
    weights = np.exp(-0.5 * ((delta_x / sigma) ** 2))

    # Multiply each weight by every data point, and sum over data points
    smoothed = np.dot(weights, ydata)

    # Nullify the result when the total weight is below threshold
    # This happens at evaluation points far from any data
    # 1-sigma away from a data point has a weight of ~0.6
    nan_mask = weights.sum(1) < null_thresh
    smoothed[nan_mask] = np.nan
    
    # Normalize by dividing by the total weight at each evaluation point
    # Nullification above avoids divide by zero warning shere
    smoothed = smoothed / weights.sum(1)

    
    return smoothed
```